# What makes showgrid=true or showgrid=top displace my clip to the right?

Tags: pstricks

The following code is trivial but important to show the problem. When I activate the `showgrid` with `true` or `top` option, my graphics object gets shifted to right as shown in the following animation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\Atom{\psframe(1,2)(2,3)}

\begin{document}

% NO problem WITHOUT showgrid or with showgrid=bottom
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](2,4)
    \begin{psclip}{\Atom}
        \psframe*(2,4)
    \end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}

% get shifted to the right with showgrid=true or showgrid=top
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](2,4)
    \begin{psclip}{\Atom}
        \psframe*(2,4)
    \end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Warning:

- `showgrid=true` is equal to `showgrid=top` rather than `showgrid=bottom`.
- The statement on page 4 of `pst-news12.pdf` might wrongly be typed.

What makes this displacement?

Comment: What does `showgrid=top` leads to? It will include `\psgrid` at the **end** of the `pspicture`-environment. This may be the problem, as everything gets shifted by drawing the grid at the very end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this version: http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
It has a bugfix for that.

Comment: The documentation was also incorrectly typed. `showgrid=true` should be identical to `showgrid=top` rather than `showgrid=bottom`. See page 4 of `pst-news12.pdf`.

Comment: There is one more bug: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8793447#8793447

Comment: Yes. But in general, `showgrid` activated in `pspicture` is for navigational purposes when constructing the diagram. For me, `showgrid=bottom` or `showgrid=top` should take `unit` defined outside the `pspicture`. And `\psgrid` should be used for other purposes. It is just an opinion. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Notice my comment above:

> What does `showgrid=top` leads to? It will include `\psgrid` at the **end** of the `pspicture`-environment. This may be the problem, as everything gets shifted by drawing the grid at the very end...

This solution will produce a correct version (draw grid first to set everything right and draw another one at the end to get it on top):

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](2,4)
    \begin{psclip}{\Atom}
        \psframe*(2,4)
    \end{psclip}
    \psgrid[style=gridstyle]
\end{pspicture}
```

There is a white space at the end of

```
      \ifx#1t
```

in the following code snippet.

```
% -----------  hv 20120219 -------------------
\newpsstyle{gridstyle}{subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10,gridlabels=8pt}
%\define@boolkey[psset]{pstricks}[]{showgrid}[true]{}
\newif\ifshowgrid
\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{showgrid}[b]{\pst@@showgrid#1\@nil}
\def\pst@@showgrid#1#2\@nil{%
  \ifx#1b\showgridtrue\def\showgridp@s{0}\else%            bottom
    \ifx#1f\showgridfalse\else
      \ifx#1t
        \ifx#2r\showgridtrue\def\showgridp@s{0}\else%      true->bottom
               \showgridtrue\def\showgridp@s{1}\fi%        top
  \fi\fi\fi%
}
```